# Issue when using "Workspace Clean" in Azure devops

Tags: azure, yaml, azure-pipelines

I've got privately hosted pipelines using Azure DevOps and want to be able to clean the directory before each deployment. I found that I could use workspace: clean all which works and deletes all of the content in the directory, the issue being that the task immediately fails afterwards with the error:

[image]

I don't understand why this error is happening, it clearly deletes the content but then immediately fails . Has anybody else encountered this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ##[error]The directory is not empty. :XXX

When other processes are using the contents of the target folder, I run into a similar issue.

For example:

When I set the `clean: all` and keep the folder opening in File Explorer, I get the error.

[image]

To solve this issue, you could try the following points:

1. Check if the target folder is using by other processes.
2. You can restart the local machine to block the background process。
3. Try to manually delete the folder `D:\azagent\A5\_work\15\client_build` and check if it could work.

Comment: Closing the folder solved it, however that isn't a very nice error message :-\